# Create Table in SQL where table name is from digits

Tags: mysql, sql

When I try do next

```
mysql> CREATE TABLE '20181020';
```

sql return an error:

```
 ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual 
 that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use 
 near ''20181020'' at line 1
```

How can I solve it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [When to use single quotes, double quotes, and back ticks in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11321491/when-to-use-single-quotes-double-quotes-and-back-ticks-in-mysql)

Answer (score 1):

You needt to wrap identifier with backticks:

```
CREATE TABLE `20181020`(id INT);
```

I propose not to do so and use proper meaningful naming. Using date as name of table suggest that it could be table-per-date antipattern.

Related article: [SELECT * FROM sales + @yymm](http://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html#Sales_yymm)

Answer (score 1):

your can also use double quote for this type of table name

```
CREATE TABLE "20181020" (id INT);
insert into "20181020" values(1)
```

But this type of naming is not standard practice

Comment: Don't you also need "ansi quote" mode?

Answer (score 0):

The other answers cover the solution, which is to use backticks.

Let me add that using non-standard identifiers is a bad idea.  If you start naming columns as number as well, who wants to figure out the differences between `20181020.1`, `20181020`.`1`, and `20181020.1`.  Is it so hard to use a prefix:  `t_20181020`?

But you don't want to do that either.  Let me explain.  Presumably, if you have one table called `20181020`, then tomorrow you will want another table `20181021`.  This is a really bad database design.

You should be putting all the data into a single table, with a `date` column specifying the date.  You can then run queries over *one* table to see changes over time -- for instance.

If the tables are large and you want the ability to manipulate each day separately, then you use *table partitioning* to store each day's worth separately.  This is handy, because partitions can be archived, restored, and dropped independently of other partitions.